# Is there a downside to having Cron execute a command via cURL instead of the PHP processor?

Tags: php, cron

Because I'm using a PHP framework with routing set up, it's much more straightforward to just set my Cron command to be whatever the same URL is that I would type in the browser; using cURL I can do this.

Example:

```
10 * * * * curl "http://domain.com/forum/cron_daily_digests" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**Question: Does this have disadvantages over running it via the PHP parser?**

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/virtual/username/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Because of the controller / method framework setup, my script requires URL routing to know what pieces to load.

Before I dug into a different way to do this, I wanted to see if it wasn't just ok to do it via cURL.

Comment: What framework are you using?  Some of them have a CLI-based routes...

Comment: Good call...Using the Kohana routing system - Looks like I can do CLI routes...Still curious if there's a downside to cURL though.

Answer (score 0):

While there are no *concrete* downsides, there are some things to be worried about.

- It takes up a connection to the web server.  Usually not a problem.
- The script has to obey the usual rules and return a response before the client times out.
- The script has to be in an accessible place.  You'll want to apply some access control rules to the directory containing it.

It's ugly, it's not advised, but it will work.  Sounds like PHP, all right...

Comment: If the cron jobs in question are usually built to be tested in the browser anyway (before getting scheduled to cron, or during maitenance) it seems like point 2 and 3 wouldn't be relevant. As you said, 1 shouldn't be a problem (assuming it's not a huge process). Do you have reference cite as to why it's not advised?